# Cytoscape Force directed layout edge weights

Tags: cytoscape

I am using Cytoscape 3.10.1 on Windows 10.
I created a network with historic connections, e.g. Person A interacts with Person B. The network is not directed. So I have a long list of Nodes and Edges. I used the Tool "Analyze Network" and get a parameter for each edge in a column called "EdgeBetweeness". I appy a Force-Directed layout using the column EdgeBetweeness (values are numeric (floating point)) and get the result.

BUT
In the properties of a force-directed layout you can choose what are the minimum and maximum values to consider among other things. However, whatever a put in the fields the layout doesent change. But if I change the default values for the weights, the layout changes completely.
Which leads me to the conclusion, that the values in the column EdgeBetweeness are not really applied and instead each edge uses the default value.
Furthermore I would expect that, when my values are in the range of the minimal and maximal values to consider, a change of the "default" value should not have any influence AT ALL.

So, any ideas what I am doing or thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what values you are setting for the minimum and maximum edge weights.  The EdgeBetweenness values are not normalizes.  For example, if I calculate the EdgeBetweenness for the sample Yeast Perturbation network, I get values between 2 and 18,270.

The default minimum and maximum values for the Prefuse Force Directed Layout or 0 and 1, respectively.  Therefore, since all edges lay outside of the range, the default edge weight will almost always be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But maybe you missunderstood me. Lets take the yeast example: As you say the values for EdgeBetweenness are not normalized and are between 2 and 18k. In the settings for "Prefuse Force Directed Layout" you can set "The minimum edge weight to consider" and maximum respectively. However, whatever values you put in these fields nothing changes. I would expect that the programm uses the values from my table which are in between min and max and everything outside that range to be the default value (which you can also set). But min max values do not change the network